# Non-Prolog logic programming

Tags: programming-languages, logic-programming

Are there any good non-Prolog or Prolog-based logic programming languages ?

Who has or any good experience with it?

Comment: Off the top of my head Scheme and Lisp come to mind... what kind of application are you trying to develop?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll 
Although logic programming module _could_ be developed in functional programming languages such as LISP/Scheme, but in direct sense - no, they not belongs to [logic-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Logic_programming_languages) language category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly recommend [The Reasoned Schemer, by Dan Friedman, Oleg Kiselyov, and Will Byrd](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262562146). It introduces miniKanren, a small (three core operators) logic programming language built atop Scheme. It's a joy to use, particularly with the [`matche`](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~lkuper/papers/lambdae.pdf) macro that allows unifying pattern matches.

Answer (score 8):

[Answer Set Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming) is an extremely powerful logic programming paradigm. I've had a lot of success with the [clasp/clingo answer set solver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/potassco/files/potassco_guide/2010-10-04/guide.pdf/download).

Answer (score 4):

I was introduced to DLV and models through answer set programming, which is basically logic programming.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at theorem proof assistants, like [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/), [HOL](http://hol.sourceforge.net/) and [Isabelle](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/).

Some type systems (e.g., in [Agda2](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php)) can be regarded as logic programming too.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's accurate to classify Coq as a logic programming language. Is it able to solve [constraint satisfaction problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) in the same way that Prolog does?

Comment: It might be possible to do unification and backtracking in Coq, but it still has [several bugs](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/UnificationProblems) that have not yet been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You might check out CLIPS. It's structured like Lisp (lots of parens) but it's designed for building expert systems; I haven't seen a problem that Prolog solves that CLIPS couldn't. Like Prolog, its based on building facts and then running queries against them.

Comment: The approach is different though. CLIPS is a "forward chaining rules based system" (like [Jess](http://www.jessrules.com/) is for Java), unlike Prolog which is a "backward chaining rule based system (nominally based on a fragment of classical first-order logic and a specific constructive "theorem prover". It is the non-logic parts are what make it live though. Now ... being based on "logic" one has a general plan what is being computed, unlike in forward chainers where what is actually happening is far less clear.

Answer (score 2):

There's also pretty fast miniKanren implementation written in [Clojure](http://clojure.org), called [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic).

There are also a few tutorials on using it:

https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/A-Core.logic-Primer

https://github.com/frenchy64/Logic-Starter/wiki

http://objectcommando.com/blog/2011/11/04/the-magical-island-of-kanren-core-logic-intro-part-1/

http://clojure.com/blog/2011/12/08/lojic-part-two.html

Answer (score 1):

Mercury and Oz spring to mind.  There's also Datalog which is a restricted (non-Turing complete) version of Prolog.